# ViewModelProvider() creates an error, although own activity is extending AppCompatActivity

Tags: java, android

Currently, I want to follow the Android Tutorial here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#13

I wanted to include the idea of the tutorial into my own project and created my own activity "WordsList" and extended the same classes like the tutorial. All went fine, but "this" in the last line of my snippet throws an error "Cannot resolve constructor ViewModelProvider(...)". In my opinion that makes absolutely no sense, because both classes MainActivity and WordsList are extending the same class?! To dig deeper I downloaded the github project and opened in Android Studio and started it on my phone. It worked! I am absolutely clueless what can cause this difference.

The corresponding snippet of MainActivity is here on github: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/MainActivity.java

Here is my snippet:

```
public class WordsList extends AppCompatActivity {

// Room DB strategies ...
private WordViewModel wordViewModel;
public static final int NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1; // Request code

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_words);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    final WordListAdapter adapter = new WordListAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    // Get a new or existing ViewModel from the ViewModelProvider.
    wordViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel.class);
```

Comment: have you compared the imports?

Comment: Two things top of my head: 1. check if you have same dependencies for `AppCompatActivity`. 2. check from where it is imported from. Its androidx?..or is is support library? Compare those two project dependencies.

Comment: Thanks - I checked these things. Which makes me curious was, that now the constructor expects two params instead of one and should be called by using a factory. Maybe that will bring me to a solution. Anyway the gradle-files look somewhat similar on a first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, these days you need to call

```
// Get a new or existing ViewModel from the ViewModelProvider.
wordViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WordViewModel.class);
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders), the following way is deprecated:
`ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);`

This is to be used now:
`MyViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);`

My only problem was that I hadn't exported this dependency in my module gradle file:
`implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-beta01"`

As soon as I included this dependency, all my issues went away.

Comment: Great answer. Had the same issue and updated to 2.2.0 and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, updated the

```
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0"
```

to

```
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
```

The constructor `ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner owner)` is introduced in 2.2.0 
The docs are a little iffy here

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you are using the 'new' androidx. Here's a [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) to the google docs to migrate your current project to an androidx one.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the provider into the manifest?

```
     <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.my.own.app.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>


    </provider>
```